# Controlling data dependencies in the Unit of Work / Repository pattern with Autofac

Tags: c#, constructor, autofac, repository-pattern, unit-of-work

This should hopefully be easy to explain, but I'm not sure how to implement the solution into my DI container (Autofac).

I've got a Repository

```
public class ClientRepository
{
    public ClientRepository(MyContext context)
    {

    }
}
```

And then a Unit-Of-Work

```
public class UnitOfWork
{
    public UnitOfWork(MyContext context, ClientRepository repository)
    {

    }
}
```

The unit-of-work/repository pattern dictates that the DataContext that the Unit-Of-Work is instantiated with should be passed into the constructor of the Repository, that way everything is using the same DataContext

In other words, AutoFac should essentially should do this...

```
MyContext context = new MyContext();
ClientRepository clientRepository = new ClientRepository(context);
UnitOfWork unitOfWork = new UnitOfWork(context, clientRepository);
```

How can I tell Autofac to wire this up correctly?

---

In response to Cyril's comment about using Func>...

I have a class "ClientService" that needs one or more of these UnitOfWorks.  In the example below, there should be no dependency sharing across the unit of works for "Add" and "Delete" (Unless I've registered a dependency as a Singleton).  If I don't use Func>, e.g. separate scopes, how could I achieve this separation?

```
public class ClientService
{
    private readonly Func<Owned<UnitOfWork>> _unitOfWorkFactory;

    public ClientService(Func<Owned<UnitOfWork>> unitOfWorkFactory)
    {
        _unitOfWorkFactory = unitOfWorkFactory;
    }

    public AddClients(Clients c)
    {
        using(var uoc = _unitOfWorkFactory())
        {

        }
    }

    public DeleteClients(Clients C)
    {
        using(var uoc = _unitOfWorkFactory())
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You want to contol scope of the service, you should read [Controlling scope and lifetime](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/lifetime/) from the Autofac documentation for more information

Comment: Thanks @CyrilDurand, that's the kick in the butt I needed.  I'm thinking the solution here is to inject a Func<Owned<UnitOfWork>>, and register my dependencies as InstancePerLifeTimeScope(), that way I have a factory that generates UnitOfWork's that I just have to dispose of when I'm done.

Comment: I love `Func<Owned<T>>` because it let you control the scope of the component inside another one but you should definitively avoid it and let *Autofac* manages everything except you have a good reason to use `Func<Owned<T>>`. In this case I don't get it ? `InstancePerLifetimeScope` or `InstancePerRequest` should be enough. Could you update the question to add more background information?

Answer (score -1):

To make Autofac essentially do what you want you need:

1. Create container
2. Register all modules you need in container
3. Register all types you need in that modules
4. Set DependencyResolver in Global.asax.cs
5. See usage example (mvc)

So

1. Creating container

```cs
    public static class DependencyContainer
    {
        internal static IContainer Container;

        public static IContainer CreateContainer(Assembly assembly)
        {
            var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
            builder.RegisterControllers(assembly);

            IModule[] modules =
            {
                //You don't have to create lots of modules...
                //but it would be better to have different modules for different application layers
                new DataModule( /*some params if you need*/),
                new DataAccessModule( ),
                //new BusinessLogicModule(),
                //...
            };

            foreach (var module in modules)
            {
                builder.RegisterModule(module);
            }

            return Container;
        }        
    }
```

2-3. Implementing modules used in container and register types

DataModule:

```
internal class DataModule : Module
{
    protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        //When you specify InstancePerRequest it means that everything (resolved via this DI) 
        //is using the same DataContext for current request
        builder.RegisterType<MyContext>().As<MyContext>().InstancePerRequest();
    }
}
```

DataAccessModule:

```
internal class DataAccessModule : Module
{
    protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.RegisterType<UnitOfWork>().As<UnitOfWork>().InstancePerRequest();
        builder.RegisterType<ClientRepository>().As<ClientRepository>().InstancePerRequest();
        //if you are using generic repository you can register all them in one line like this: 
        //builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(Repository<>)).As(typeof(IRepository<>)).InstancePerRequest();
    }
}
```

4. Set DependencyResolver in Global.asax.cs

   ```
   public class MvcApplication : HttpApplication
   {
       protected void Application_Start()
       {
           //Default Application_Start() content       
           //...

           //Using our DI
           var container = DependencyContainer.CreateContainer(typeof(MvcApplication).Assembly);
           DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(container));
       }
   }
   ```
5. Usage example

   ```
   public class MyController : Controller
   {
       private readonly UnitOfWork _unitOfWork;
       private readonly ClientRepository _clientRepository;

       public MyController(UnitOfWork unitOfWork, ClientRepository clientRepository)
       {
           _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
           _clientRepository = clientRepository;
       }

       //When you are calling action DoSomething, you don't have to worry about constructor params (DI will pass them)
       public ActionResult DoSomething()
       {
           _clientRepository.DoSomething();

           return PartialView("DoSomething");
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: I don't see how this helps solve my problem of using the same instance in two separate/dependent classes.